# How can I remove the bold from a headline?

Tags: css, xhtml

I have a headline:

```
<h1>THIS IS A HEADLINE</h1>
```

How do I make the phrase "THIS IS..." not to be bold and the rest without a change?

I couldn't find any relevant tag in text-decoration.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

The heading looks bold because of its *large size*. If you have applied bold or want to change behaviour, you can do:

```css
h1 { font-weight: normal; }
```

More: *[3.2. Font weight: the font-weight property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-weight-prop)*

Comment: I am quite sure that in some browsers headings automatically become bold. I recommend  adding `font-weight:normal;` **always** if you want non-bold headings.

Answer (score 20):

Try `font-weight:normal;`

```css
h1 {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

```html
<h1><span style="font-weight:bold;">THIS IS</span> A HEADLINE</h1>
```

But be sure that h1 is marked with

```css
font-weight: normal;
```

You can also set the style with a id or class attribute.

Answer (score 7):

You want [font-weight](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-weight-prop), not text-decoration (along with suitable additional markup, such as `<em>` or `<span>`, so you can apply different styling to different parts of the heading)

Answer (score 4):

*style* is accordingly vis CSS. An example:

```
<h1 class="mynotsoboldtitle">I'm not bold</h1>
<style>
    .mynotsoboldtitle { font-weight: normal; }
</style>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"accordingly vis CSS"*? Even with *[vis-à-vis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vis-%C3%A0-vis#Preposition)* it would still seem incomprehensible.

Comment: No idea! The comment was made over 11 years ago! Apologies!

Answer (score 2):

```html
<h1><span>This is</span> a Headline</h1>
```

```css
h1 { font-weight: normal; text-transform: uppercase; }
h1 span { font-weight: bold; }
```

I'm not sure if it was just for the sake of showing us, but as a side note, you should always set uppercase text with CSS :)

Answer (score 2):

For "THIS IS" not to be bold, add `<span></span>` around the text:

```html
<h1>><span>THIS IS</span> A HEADLINE</h1>
```

And in style

```css
h1 span{font-weight: normal}
```

Comment: Why the extra "`>`"? It doesn't seem to be [well-formed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_element).

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do like that in the HTML part:

```html
<span>Heading Text</span>
```

And in the CSS, you can make it as an h1 block using display:

```css
span{
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

You will get it as a h1 without bold.

If you want it bold, just add this to the CSS:

```css
font-weight: bold;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `font-weight:100` or lighter: this is working with i.e. [Opera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29) 16 and older, but I do not know why the `h1` tags in Firefox are bolder, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the bold, you can use the code below,

```css
h1 {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

But for "THIS IS" not to be bold, add `<span></span>` around the text,

```html
<h1><span>THIS IS</span> A HEADLINE</h1>
```

And in style,

```css
h1 span {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Code example result,

```css
h1 span {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>THIS IS</span> A HEADLINE</h1>
```